# .htaccess simple login throws 500 error page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, password-protection

I have the following .htaccess file that I use for a WP site:

```
# Force download of .csv files
AddType application/octet-stream .csv

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Which works fine, the first line just forces `.csv` files to download and the rest redirects requests to the `index.php` file, then I just tried to add some simple `.htaccess` authentication by adding this at the top of the file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

The `.htpasswd` file is in my root directory and it prompts me to enter the username and password I set, but if I type it correctly I get a 500 error page now, I'm not sure if it's related to WP or if I'm doing something wrong in my `.htaccess` file, I tried moving the code to the end of the file too but same results.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your logs say?

Comment: Nvm for some reason it's working now, probably my host's fault :(